# How to empty() element but keep event handlers etc?

Tags: jquery

How can you empty an element and re-use the elements and keep event handlers etc.?

http://jsfiddle.net/WrMbG/

```
<div></div>

var inp = $('<input type="text" />')
    .keydown(function(){
        alert('keydown');
    });

$('div').append(inp);
$('div').empty();
$('div').append(inp);
```

all event handlers and etc. is destroyed when you empty an element.. how can you avoid this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) on the child instead:

```
inp.detach();
```

If you have multiple elements

```
var saved = $("div").children().detach();
```

From the documentation on `empty`:

> To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data
>   and event handlers from the child elements before removing the
>   elements themselves.

Comment: Note that `$el.children().detach()` differs from `$el.empty()` in *two* ways: it preserves jQuery data and event handlers, as noted here, and it also won't remove text nodes that are direct children of `$el`. This second difference may or may not be desirable; if it isn't, you'll want to call `$el.empty()` after `$el.children().detach()`.

Answer (score 0):

try `.detach()` -

```
$('div input[type="text"]').detach();
```

Answer (score -1):

You might try using [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
var inp = $('<input type="text" id="myinput" />'); 

$('#myinput').live('keydown', function(){
    alert('keydown');
});

$('div').append(inp);
$('div').empty();
$('div').append(inp);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using jQuery.live(), which searches for newly created elements (whereas keydown will just try elements that were created before the keydown handler was created).

```
<div></div>

var inp = $('<input type="text" />');

// edit: live won't work when chaining it, so attaching separately
$("input").live('keydown', function(){
    alert('keydown');
});

$('div').append(inp);
$('div').empty();
$('div').append(inp);
```

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for more info.

Comment: Oops, thanks what I get for not checking my code before submitting it. .live() didn't like it when I was chaining it, so I attached the live handler after var inp was declated.  Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/By85N/

Answer (score -2):

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WrMbG/1/)

When you create your `inp` variable, it's a unique jQuery object. If you want to use it multiple times, you need to clone it in order to be able to reuse it. Supply the `true` parameter to the `clone()` method to get a deep copy, include events.